# How to make Bootstrap Carousel to start from the first slide on button click?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using a Bootstrap Carousel in my website and want to achieve this: The carousel should reset and start from the first slide on button click.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes of course... please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function() {
   $('.carousel').carousel(0); 
});
```

[Bootstrap documentation : .carousel(number)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#.carousel%28number%29)